# Redirect deep link URLs to new domain with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, redirect

Say for example you currently host a site www.domain.com and you are going to move it to www.new-domain.com.  Now, currently you're blog structure is www.domain.com/2012/09/post-name and your new blog structure will be www.new-domain.com/blog/post-name.  I know I can do a 301 permanent redirect on domain.com to point to new-domain.com, but is there a way to capture the long-tail URL and RegEx a rewrite with htaccess.  Usually I would do:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://domain.com/blog/$3
```

If I need to change URL structure within the same domain.  Will this catch redirects from the old domain also?

Comment: Can you not just do: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Can you expand on your thought process for this one?

Comment: If I'm right in understanding, you want to redirect all links (even really deep ones) to another website, but don't want the hassle of writing out long bits like that? Or am I wrong?

Comment: I think I'm wrong after re-reading it. :-P

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've got both domains pointing to the same directory otherwise asking about redirects from the old domain wouldn't make any sense.

If you've got a redirect on the new domain document root, you'd never ever see requests from the old domain, and vice versa.

If both domains share the same document root, you'll need to do the check against the host:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The domains are hosted on different servers with completely different DNS zones.  My question was whether or not this was even possible.  To have domain.com/year/day/postname redirect to new-domain.com/blog/postname without manually redirecting every post, doing some kind of dns redirect and then a regex to catch the tail...you're correct that it MIGHT not make sense, that's why I am asking.

Comment: @RobBennet What you had would do the trick, or using the mod_rewrite solution in this answer.